# Facebook Graph API - retrieve photos from album INCLUDING source (original photo url)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I retrieve the list of photos in an album like following:

```
String url = 
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/" + 
     albumId + 
     "/photos?fields=created_time,height,id,images,picture,name,updated_time,width";
```

There seems to be no field `source` in the album request... The `picture` array contains a lot of image urls, but it seems that it does NOT contain the original url. I see images where I can't find the original image in the `picture` array...

So the only solution I found is to make a request for every image like following:

```
 String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/" + id + "?fields=source";
```

And extracting the `source` value from this answer.

*Is there any better approach?* I know width, height and many urls, but I need the original image url as well... It's somehow weird to make a request for every single image just for that information...

Comment: PS i dont think you eve rget original url, cause facebook NEVER deletes images even if author deleted, so that way they have ability to prevent you frm getting deleted images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all this data in one go, by using the [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion) syntax:

```
/album-id?fields=photos{created_time,height,id,images,picture,name,updated_time,width,source}
```

Comment: Perfect, didn't know about that feature. Thanks